# Is it possible to decrease the height of the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I want to decrease the hight of the **status bar**, is it possible? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: Hiding it would not be okay? The default height looks really minimal if you still want its functionality.

Comment: Decreasing the height of the status bar is not possible. It is not something you should do. Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, not officially. I assume you got that screenshot from the Human Interface Guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/, so you also might have seen their reasoning for this:

> Use the system-provided status bar. People expect the status bar to be consistent systemwide. Don’t replace it with a custom status bar.

Comment: yea I am aware this massage but  I need to decrease the hight of the status bar . if it is possible .

Answer (score 1):

No you can not change the size of the status bar, but you can hide the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to decrease the height of the status bar.

Why I think so:

- haven't ever seen such design
- there is no more space to lower it since it's already quite short and it would make it look strange or decrease the fonts etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide the status bar temporarily if that is what your app need,  but remember that you must hide the status bar depending on the attention you want to grab from the user. Apple describes it better, so here it is.

According to Apple:

> Consider temporarily hiding the status bar when displaying full-screen media. A status bar can be distracting when users are trying to focus on media. Temporarily hide these elements to provide a more immersive experience. The Photos app, for example, hides the status bar and other interface elements during browsing of full-screen photos.